# How select unique values by a field and print all other fields?

Tags: sql-server, select

I need to get the unique rows from a table with timestamp field which is not unique.

I tried to run with distinct and removing timestamp field. It gives perfect result but I miss the timestamp. Timestamp is necessary for me.

This gives right result but I miss tstamp field.

```
SELECT distinct      person_id, status, type, strowner
FROM            tbl_wa_requests_h
WHERE        (person_id = 1128)
```

This has tstamp field but then result is not what I need.

```
SELECT       person_id, status, type, strowner, db_tstamp
FROM            tbl_wa_requests_h
WHERE        (person_id = 1128)
```

Expected Result

```
personid - status - type - email - tstamp
1128 -  0 - t1 -    wandam@gmail.com -  2019-08-18 11:37:15.6893649
1128 -  1 - t2 -    stever@gmail.com -  2019-08-18 11:41:04.8658361
```

Actual Result

```
personid - status - type - email - tstamp
1128 -  0 - t1 -    wandam@gmail.com -  2019-08-18 11:37:15.6883648
1128 -  0 - t1 -    wandam@gmail.com -  2019-08-18 11:37:15.6883648
1128 -  0 - t1 -    wandam@gmail.com -  2019-08-18 11:37:15.6883648
1128 -  0 - t1 -    wandam@gmail.com -  2019-08-18 11:37:15.6893649
1128 -  0 - t1 -    wandam@gmail.com -  2019-08-18 11:37:15.6893649
1128 -  1 - t2 -    stever@gmail.com -  2019-08-18 11:41:04.8658361
1128 -  1 - t2 -    stever@gmail.com -  2019-08-18 11:41:04.9328798
1128 -  1 - t2 -    stever@gmail.com -  2019-08-18 11:41:05.0309459
1128 -  1 - t2 -    stever@gmail.com -  2019-08-18 11:41:04.9278764
1128 -  1 - t2 -    stever@gmail.com -  2019-08-18 11:41:04.9278764
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use group clause

the code query should look as bellow:

```
SELECT person_id, status, type, strowner, max(db_tstamp)
FROM   tbl_wa_requests_h
WHERE  (person_id = 1128)
GROUP BY person_id, status, type, strowner
```